# Silverstripe 3.1: Default Controller/Route

Tags: url-routing, yaml, silverstripe

I'd like to add a default route to Silverstripe. At present, there are some routes in my application, being /dev, /admin and /api. I would like all other trafic that's not in a  (virtual) subdirectory to be handled by a separate controller.

I've been playing around with the YAML config system, but I don't seem to be able to wrap my head around it.

So basicly I want to do the following

- /dev -> basic SS functionality, should be doing what it does :-)
- /admin -> cms module
- /api -> Restful api module,

But every other path should point to MyOwnController.

- /asdfsdfsd -> MyOwnController
- /23-asdf   -> MyOwnController
  etc.

It's not necessary that /asda/asd also reroutes to MyOwnController.

I made a /mysite/_config/routes.yml file, containing the following:

```
---
Name: myroutes
After: 'framework/routes#coreroutes'
---
Director:
  rules:
    '$Path': 'MyOwnController'
```

This breaks the site (only 404's). How should this be set up? I could start fiddling in the _config.php, but I'd rather adhere to the standard :-)

Comment: You don't need a $ in front of the path - so 'somepath': 'MyController' should work. Also, did you run a /dev/build?flush=1 after making changes? It's a common clanger!

Comment: "somepath: MyController" would, afaik, only route all traffic of www.mysite.com/somepath to the controller. I want "somepath" to be arbitrary. Like http://twitter.com/username, where "username" can be anything you want. And yes, I am flushing myself senseless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing it via .hataccess? Something like the following (not tested):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/your/default/route
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/framework
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Security
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/themes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/your/default/route/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Nice thinking! But that would break things if I would decide on adding pages to the site later on. Also It would introduce an additional 301/302 redirect, that I'd like to avoid. But definately an option to keep in mind... For now I would like to keep things inside Silverstripe.

Comment: I was playing around with your answer, and it works, but I had to add some rules to prevent a redirect loop. Also, I'd like the assets dir not to be rewritten. But I still would like to have a native SS solution :-)

Comment: I added your RewriteCond by hand, now my .htaccess rule seems more correct. Anyway I don't think that with this solution we introduced an additional 301/302 redirect, because we didn't use the R=301 option in RewriteRule, it's up to apache to serve a different page to the original browser request.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right about the extra 301. I'll wait a day or so if someone comes up with the holy grail, otherwise I will accept your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Aaaand... added another route that should be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted this from the CMS ModelAsController routes and should work, but is untested.

```
---
Name: myroutes
Before: '*'
After: '#rootroutes'
---
Director:
  rules:
    '$Path//$Action/$ID/$OtherID': 'MyOwnController'
```

https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/blob/3.1/_config%2Froutes.yml

Remember to flush=1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this does not work. I get the following error: Fatal error: Based on their before & after rules two fragments both need to be before/after each other in ...